# Matplotlib Circle patch does not have smooth edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to display Matplotlib patches using the `Circle` function on a map plot using cartopy geographical projections. Apparently this is supposed to give a smooth, near scale-free circular patch, however the edges are very polygonal. Strangely, `CirclePolygon`, the polygonal approximation counterpart of `Circle`, produces a *smoother* circle, albeit still not as smooth as I would like.

This is pretty much all the code as it pertains to adding the plot and the patches:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
img_extent = [340, 348, -35.5, -31]
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mollweide(), extent = img_extent)
patch_coords = [[342.5833, -34.5639],[343.4042, -34.3353],[343.8500, -33.8728],
                 [344.4917, -33.7636],[344.9250, -33.3108],[345.1333, -32.6811],
                   [344.9233, -32.1583]]
for pair in patch_coords:
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Circle(xy = pair, radius = 0.5, 
                   color = 'r', alpha = 0.3, rasterized = None, 
                      transform = ccrs.Geodetic()))
ax.scatter(ra1, dec1, transform = ccrs.Geodetic(), rasterized = True, s = 1, 
             marker = ".", c = 'g', label = 'z < 0.025')
ax.scatter(ra2, dec2, transform = ccrs.Geodetic(), rasterized = True, s = 2, 
             marker = ".", c = 'b', label = '0.25 < z < 0.034')
ax.scatter(ra3, dec3, transform = ccrs.Geodetic(), rasterized = True, s = 0.75, 
             marker = ".", c = 'grey', label = '0.034 < z < 0.05')
```

Which produces this

[image: Plot]

I've tried looking through the available arguments but none seem to fix it. Is there a reason why it comes out like this and is there any way to make it smoother?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because of `projection = ccrs.Mollweide()`. A polygon is much easier to project than a curve. Perhaps the curve is being quickly resampled as a polygon with an insufficient number of points?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah, I just tried removing everything to do with the projections and that seems to be it actually. I had tried it with simpler projections and the matplotlib projections already but that didn't do anything. For some reason I didn't realize that it was actually the fact that it had a projection at all that was the problem. Makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe plotting Tissot's Indicatrices is more appropriate in your case. An Indicatrix represents a ground circle on a map projection. In many cases, the Indicatrices are rendered as ellipses as map projections do not always preserve shapes. The following is the working code that plots all the ground circles of radius = 55 km on the map projection that you desire. Read the comments in the code for some useful information.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

img_extent = [340, 348, -35.5, -31]
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mollweide(), extent = img_extent)

patch_coords = [[342.5833, -34.5639],[343.4042, -34.3353],[343.8500, -33.8728],
                 [344.4917, -33.7636],[344.9250, -33.3108],[345.1333, -32.6811],
                   [344.9233, -32.1583]]

for ix,pair in enumerate(patch_coords):
    # plot tissot indicatrix at each location 
    # n_samples = number of points forming indicatrix' perimeter
    # rad_km = 55 km. is about the angular distance 0.5 degree
    ax.tissot(rad_km=55, lons=np.array(patch_coords)[:,0][ix], \
              lats=np.array(patch_coords)[:,1][ix], n_samples=36, \
             facecolor='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.15, alpha = 0.3)

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, linewidth=1, color='blue', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

**Edit**

Since the first version of the code is not optimal.
Code update is offered as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

img_extent = [340, 348, -35.5, -31]
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mollweide(), extent = img_extent)

patch_coords = [[342.5833, -34.5639],[343.4042, -34.3353],[343.8500, -33.8728],
                 [344.4917, -33.7636],[344.9250, -33.3108],[345.1333, -32.6811],
                   [344.9233, -32.1583]]

for pair in patch_coords:
    # plot tissot indicatrix at each location 
    # n_samples = number of points forming indicatrix' perimeter
    # rad_km = 55 km. is about the angular distance 0.5 degree at equator
    ax.tissot(rad_km=55, lons=pair[0], lats=pair[1], n_samples=36, \
             facecolor='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.15, alpha = 0.3)

gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=False, linewidth=1, color='blue', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks perfect. However when I compare it to my original the circles here are clearly wider. I'm inclined to trust yours more though since it looks more like the mockup I produced using mapping software and since the Indicatrices were specifically designed for map projections! But yeah I'm just a bit puzzled to be honest since the circles I initially made also changed depending on the projection so I'm not sure why they're so "squashed". Also I'm wondering for yours how precisely I can make the km measurements fit the constant half-degree of each circle since it varies with latitude.

Comment: @KrisWalker Tissot's Indicatrix plotting in this case represents the surface circles of radius=55 km. That is, independent of the latitude of the location. The changes of size, shape, area, etc. are due to map projection distortions.

Comment: Right. But the shape of a degree-wide circle will change with latitude, which is what I'm after. If I'm not mistaken, Tissot's indicatricies with a constant surface distance radius get wider near the poles while degree-wide circles get thinner. So I'd have to assign the radius some function of latitude to use this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Cartopy does line projections with an arbitrary fixed accuracy, rather than a dynamic line-split calculation.

See e.g. :

- https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/825
- https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/363

I also think work is ongoing right now to address that.

In the meantime, to solve specific problems you can hack the `CRS.threshold` property,
as explained here : https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/8
That is, you can make it use finer steps by reprogramming the fixed value.
I think this would also fix this circle-drawing problem, though I'm not 100%